# Python replace string without certain characters after it

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, restrictions

I am trying to replace a string within a text file so that it only replaces the exact match of the string.

So if the file was:

```
"word"
"word_1"
"word1"
"wordA"
```

I want to replace just `word` with `test_1` I would do this:

```
text.replace("word", "test_1")
```

But by doing this, I am also replacing every other `word` with other text after it with that string. So the file would be like this:

```
"test_1"
"test_1_1"
"test_11"
"test_1A"
```

I want it so I can only replace `word` so that it only replaces it if there are not any lowercase letters, uppercase letters or underscores after it. I want the replace to be restricted to only exact matches so if there are other strings in the file with the same text with letters, numbers or underscores after it, they will not be affected. I also want to so if any other characters are after it that are not letters, numbers or underscores will be replaced like if it was:

```
word"
word;
word:
```

Those would be fine because they do not have letters, numbers or underscores after them.

I want this so I can replace the other strings with different things like:

```
text.replace("word", "test_1")
text.replace("word_1", "test_2")
text.replace("word1", "test_3")
text.replace("wordA", "test_4")
```

So that the file will be:

```
test_1
test_2
test_3
test_4
```

How would I do this?

Comment: This sounds like a job for regular expressions!

Comment: `re.sub(r'\bword\b', 'test_1', text)`? See http://ideone.com/UNEywY

Comment: If anyone adds a regex tag, I will close with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is not exact dup because the OP ask to exclude `;`,`:` etc

Comment: Was just writing answer but if you need a regex statement that works for your specs try: `re.sub(r'word(\d|\n|[a-zA-z]|_)+', 'test_' + str(accumulator), text)`. Accumulator is a number as you need to put at the end of `test_`

Comment: @OhadEytan: *I want it so I can only replace word so that it only replaces it if there are not any lowercase letters, uppercase letters or underscores after it.*. That is exactly what `\b` word boundary does. And `word"` will become `test"`  if we use `re.sub(r'\bword\b', 'test', text)`.

Comment: @Mike: Your regex is inappropriate, there is one serious issue with it, and two performance related issues.

Comment: @Wiktor can see one performance issue with the str() call but what else do you see?

Comment: *Alternations* of *single* character matching patterns inside a *capturing group* that is *`+`-quantified*. That might add to readability, but a non-capturing group is what you mean. If you use a character class, this will get fixed by itself.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = """word
word_1
word1
wordA
"""

replacements = {
    "word": "test_1",
    "word_1": "test_2",
    "word1": "test_3",
    "wordA": "test_4"
}

print(reduce(lambda a, b: a.replace(*b), replacements.iteritems(), data))
```