# get sentence from list of sentences with exact word match : Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list of sentences:

```
sent = ["Chocolate is loved by all.", 
        "Brazil is the biggest exporter of coffee.", 
        "Tokyo is the capital of Japan.",
        "chocolate is made from cocoa."]
```

I want to return all sentences that have the exact full word "chocolate", i.e. `["Chocolate is loved by all.", "chocolate is made from cocoa."]`.
If any sentence does not have the word "chocolate", it shouldn't be returned. The word "chocolateyyy" should not be returned either.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried doing and where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression library in python:

```
import re

sent = ["Chocolate is loved by all.", 
        "Brazil is the biggest exporter of coffee.", 
        "Tokyo is the capital of Japan.",
        "chocolate is made from cocoa."]
match_string = "chocolate"
matched_sent = [s for s in sent if len(re.findall(r"\bchocolate\b", s, re.IGNORECASE)) > 0]
print (matched_sent)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will make sure that the `search` word is actually a full word, rather than a sub-word like 'chocolateyyy'. It's also not case sensitive, so 'Chocolate' = 'chocolate' despite the first letters being capitalised differently.

```
sent = ["Chocolate is loved by all.", "Brazil is the biggest exporter of coffee.",
        "Tokyo is the capital of Japan.","chocolate is made from cocoa.", "Chocolateyyy"]

search = "chocolate"

print([i for i in sent if search in i.lower().split()])
```

Here's a more expanded version for clarity with an explanation:

```
result = []
for i in sent: # Go through each string in sent
    lower = i.lower() # Make the string all lowercase
    split = lower.split(' ') # split the string on ' ', or spaces
                     # The default split() splits on whitespace anyway though
    if search in split: # if chocolate is an entire element in the split array
        result.append(i) # add it to results
print(result)
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it was as simple as that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Consider accepting one of the answers you received (click the tick ✓ next to your favourite answer)

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
filtered_sent = [i for i in sent if 'chocolate' in i.lower()]
```

**Output**

```
['Chocolate is loved by all.', 'chocolate is made from cocoa.']
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word), you want some of the methods in [the re library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).  In particular:

> \b Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.

You can therefore search for "chocolate" using `re.search(r'\bchocolate\b', your_sentence, re.IGNORECASE)`.

The rest of the solution is just to iterate through your list of sentences and return a sublist that matches your target string.

Comment: Good one. This one is recommended where search word is more likely to be part of the other words.