# Python - How to find matching one or multiply words in a sentence

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement

So I am trying to make a small script for myself where I have one or multiply word/s and by that it is supposed to find all matching words in a randomized sentence.

etc:

```
Sentence1 = "Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow"

Sentence2 = "Is it beautiful weather"

Sentence3 = "I hope it wont be snowing here soon"

Sentence4 = "How is the weather"

Words = ['I+be', 'it+weather']
```

---

*The output is supposed to say*

```
Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow

Is it beautiful weather

I hope it wont be snowing here soon
```

and the reason why it doesn't print the first one and last one is that it does not contain *I* and *Be* and *it* and *weather*

So my question is basically how to make every *+* or any other special characters like keyword1 + keyword2 + n (Can be up from 1 to n words) and compare if those word are in the sentence

So what I tried to code was something like

```
Sentence = [
    "Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow",
    "Is it beautiful weather", "I hope it wont be snowing here soon",
    "How is the weather"]

Words = ['I', 'it+weather']

for loop_word in Words:
    for loop_setence in Sentence:
        if loop_word in loop_setence:
            print(loop_setence)
            break
```

However for now it does only print out the first sentence since I changed the Words to I for now.

What I want to do is that words in that contains more than 1 word should be adding with a special character in between etc I+be so whenever there is a I and Be inside a sentence it should print that it found that sentence - Else do not print anything.

[image: Illustration]

So my question for you is how can I continue from my point forward with me wish :) ?

Comment: `'it+weather' in sentence` searches for exact this string: `'it+weather'` which isn't there.

Comment: The first sentence contains I and be, should it be in the output?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Oh yeah that is correct, I think I need to make something that whenever there is a + in the words. it should regard it as two words I believe. but should not regard it as `it` and `weather` as two different seperated words like if I would do `['it', 'weather']

Comment: @DanielMesejo Oh my bad! Yes it is supposed to be since there is a `I and Be` in that sentence.

Comment: If this is not a simple exercise, you should use proper NLP tools instead of hacking your way around a classical problem.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I wish to understand what you meant :(

Comment: Identifying different forms/inflections of the same words is a classical and complicated problem in natural language processing (NLP) with various solutions. You should research the solution space and pick the one that suits your needs.

Comment: @EliKorvigo It is actually first time hearing it - it sounds pretty interesting I would say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
words = ['I+be', 'it+weather']
sentences = ["Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow",
             "Is it beautiful weather", "I hope it wont be snowing here soon", "How is the weather"]

def check_all(sentence, ws):
    return all(w in sentence for w in ws)

for sentence in sentences:
    if any(check_all(sentence, word.split('+')) for word in words):
        print(sentence)
```

**Output**

```
Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow
Is it beautiful weather
I hope it wont be snowing here soon
```

The function `check_all` checks if all the words from a group of words (for example `'I+be'`) are in the sentence. Then if for any group of words are in the sentence you should print the sentence. Note that you must first split on `'+'` to find if a group matches.

**UPDATE**

To match whole words only I suggest you use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), for example:

```
import re

words = ['I+be', 'it+weather']
sentences = ["Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow",
             "Is it beautiful weather", "I hope it wont be snowing here soon", "How is the weather", "With In be"]


def check_all(sentence, ws):
    """Returns True if all the words are present in the sentence"""
    return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)


for sentence in sentences:
    if any(check_all(sentence, word.split('+')) for word in words):
        print(sentence)
```

**Output**

```
Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow
Is it beautiful weather
I hope it wont be snowing here soon
```

Note that the second example does not contains `"With In be"` in the output.

**Further**

1. See the documentation on [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).
2. [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word)

Comment: I did find a issue. if you leave just etc `words = ['I', 'it+weather']` with only one word - so whenever there is a capital I inside a word it will mark it as it is inside there. but not as a Word

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere Updated the answer!

Comment: That is weird, I just run with those sentences and only printed "Stackoverflow hello testing red"

Comment: Oh thats strange. I must have forgot to do something. Let me take another look and see what mistake I did!

Comment: I just checked! You were right! It was me who did the mistake! Im truly sorry and I appreciate your answer! I think this was the correct one answer that I used atleast :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter`, `any`, `all`, and `split`

```
In [22]: Sentence1 = "Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow"
    ...:
    ...: Sentence2 = "Is it beautiful weather"
    ...:
    ...: Sentence3 = "I hope it wont be snowing here soon"
    ...:
    ...: Sentence4 = "How is the weather"
    ...:
    ...: Words = ['I+be', 'it+weather']
    ...:

In [23]: sentences = [Sentence1, Sentence2, Sentence3, Sentence4]

In [27]: list(filter(lambda s: any(all(w in s.split() for w in word.split('+')) for word in Words), sentences))
    ...:
Out[27]:
['Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow',
 'Is it beautiful weather',
 'I hope it wont be snowing here soon']
```

The comprehension returns a generator of `True` of `False` if one of the keywords are in one of the sentences. `all` will return `True` if all elements of the inner container are `True`. Conversely, `any` will return `True` if any elements of the inner container are `True`.

Checking the `'be'` doesn't return `Sentence2`

```
In [43]: Words = ['be']

In [44]: list(filter(lambda s: any(all(w in s.split() for w in word.split('+')) for word in Words), sentences))
Out[44]:
['Hello, I am new here and I hope I will be able to help and get helped from Stackoverflow',
 'I hope it wont be snowing here soon']
```

Note that this won't take into account punctuation. I.e. `'Hello' != 'Hello,'`

Comment: Hello! I did find an issue in this program, so basically whenever if you change your Words into just one word in etc `i` it will take all i that contains in any words meaning like beatiful it will print it out since it contains `i` inside it

Comment: so you are asking for whole word matches?

Comment: Yes exactly :) It might be confusion when it comes with the `+` but basically what it does is that it checks if there is etc I and be in the word which I assume the one you coded was similar but it looks only for anything that has a I and Be but what I wish is that it should work for the whole word matches and not just each characters :)

Comment: This might seem like this is the solution. However whenever I try to print out this function by doing `print(list(filter(lambda s: any(all(w in s.split() for w in word.split('+')) for word in Words), sentences)))` it gives me the answers within a list. Is it possible that it just prints out without inside a list `[Is it beaitful weather]` ?

Comment: no, you can't print out a group of things without the grouping mechanism