# Exact keyword match in string

Tags: python, string, search

I know this question has been asked almost hundred times in stack overflow but after doing lot of search and not finding my answer, I am asking this question.

I am looking to search exact word from strings something like below.

```
'svm_midrangedb_nonprod:svm_midrangedb_nonprod_root'
'svm_midrangedb_prod:svm_midrangedb_prod_root'
```

I want to search only for `'prod'` but getting both `'prod'` and `'nonprod'` in output.

Here is the code I am using:

```
re.search(r"\wprod\w", in_volumes.json()[i]['name'].split(":")[2].lower())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word)

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want `['prod','prod']` or just `['prod']` for each string?

Comment: only prod and not nonprod

Comment: What I'm asking is whether or not you want the `'prod'` portion of the `'nonprod'` word? If not, then you need to use lookbehinds.

Comment: "Python regular expression match whole word"   in this "is" starting and ending with space but in my case there is no space.

Comment: rahlf23, I dont need the portion of word rather return a complete line but if I search for prod line with nonprod should not come.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make rules to not match `nonprod` but match `prod`.

For example, maybe you can make it so that if there's `n` infront of `prod`, you exclude it like this: `[^n]prod\w`.

Or maybe some data has `n` infront of prod and you want to keep it. Then, you want to exclude if there's `non` infront of `prod` like this: `\w*(?<!non)prod\w*`.

It really depends on the rest of your data and see what kind of rules you can make/apply to them to get your desired data.

Comment: So you mean for each type of possible string I have to search possible combination either before or after of desired keyword. Surprise to know there is no sort solution and no one faces this before.

Comment: @user3114051 Yes, because you're looking for a string `prod` not a word `prod`, which usually has spaces around. You still want to match string like `intelprod` right? Then how will it know to match `intelprod` but not `nonprod`?

Comment: Yeah, agree. \w*(?<!non)prod\w* or \w*(?<!intel)prod\w* or \w*(?<!intelnon)prod\w* makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because your regular expression tell that you want a string containing `"prod"`, in order to solve that very easily you can  do the same thing you did but like follow
`re.search(r"\w_prod\w", in_volumes.json()[i]['name'].split(":")[2].lower())`
I just add a `_` character existing in your targeted string

Comment: "_" can work but in some other lines it is like svm_sqldb_prod:gso_sql_sdb1_c2_intelprodsql02_nc2pwsql0350_data_vol01 and svm_sqldb_prod:gso_sql_sdb1_c2_intelnonprodsql02_nc2pwsql0350_data_vol01

Comment: @user3114051 you can use this regex for that re.search(r"\w(?<!non)prod\w", your_string)  , for more information search positive look behind regex