# Find (possibly multi-word) phrase inside sentence in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find keywords within a sentence, where the keywords are usually single words, but can be multi-word combos (like "cost in euros"). So if I have a sentence like `cost in euros of bacon` it would find `cost in euros` in that sentence and return true.

For this, I was using this code:

```
if any(phrase in line for phrase in keyword['aliases']:
```

where `line` is the input and `aliases` is an array of phrases that match a keyword (like for cost in euros, it's `['cost in euros', 'euros', 'euro cost']`).

However, I noticed that it was also triggering on word parts. For example, I had a match phrase of `y` and a sentence of `trippy cake`. I'd not expect this to return true, but it does, since it apparently finds the `y` in `trippy`. How do I get this to only check whole words? Originally I was doing this keyword search with a list of words (essentially doing `line.split()` and checking those), but that doesn't work for multi-word keyword aliases.

Comment: in your sentences and keywords are there punctuation?

Comment: @Primusa no, no punctuation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
import re

aliases = [
    'cost.',
    '.cost',
    '.cost.',
    'cost in euros of bacon',
    'rocking euros today',
    'there is a cost inherent to bacon',
    'europe has cost in place',
    'there is a cost.',
    'I was accosted.',
    'dealing with euro costing is painful']
phrases = ['cost in euros', 'euros', 'euro cost', 'cost']

matched = list(set([
    alias
    for alias in aliases
    for phrase in phrases
    if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(phrase), alias)
    ]))

print(matched)
```

Output:

```
['there is a cost inherent to bacon', '.cost.', 'rocking euros today', 'there is a cost.', 'cost in euros of bacon', 'europe has cost in place', 'cost.', '.cost']
```

Basically, we're grabbing all matches, using pythons `re` module as our test, including cases where multiple `phrase`s occur in a given `alias`, using a compound `list comprehension`, then using `set()` to trim duplicates from the `list`, then using `list()` to coerce the `set` back into a `list`.

Refs:

Lists:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

List comprehensions:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Sets:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

re (or regex):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: Almost, but I've found it doesn't quite work when the keyword is at the end of a sentence and therefore has no space at the end.

Comment: Update my answer. This should cover your use cases.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Note that I kinda overexplained in my answer here. Not meaning to imply your don't get it. Just trying to make the answer more useful for future folks looking for answers.