# Replace word only if it stands alone

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a function with which I want to anonymize texts by replacing the name of a person by 'visitor'.

To do so, I have written the following function:

```
def replaceName(text, name):
    newText = text.replace(name, 'visitor')
    return str(newText)
```

And I apply it using:

```
all_transcripts['msgText'] = all_transcripts.apply(lambda x: replaceName(x['msgText'], x['nameGuest']), axis=1)
```

However, this also replaces the name if it is a part of another word. Therefore, I want to only replace the instances where this word stands by itself. I have tried it as `" "+name+" "`, however, this does not work if the name is at the beginning or end of a sentence.

Furthermore, I have considered: [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word). However, here they say how to find such words, but not how to replace it. I am having trouble to both find and replace it.

Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

text = "Mark this isMark example Mark."

print (re.sub(r"\bMark\b", "visitor", text))
```

output:

```
visitor this isMark example visitor.
```

Comment: The edited solution will work.