# How do I strip away these 0 values without stripping away non-zero values that end in zero?

Tags: python

I am working with heart rate data and I want to strip away the numbers that the heart rate never reached for that day.

Some code:

```
result_list = [
    '0 instances of 44 bpm', 
    '0 instances of 45 bpm', 
    '10 instances of 46 bpm', 
    '22 instances of 47 bpm', 
    '354 instances of 65 bpm', 
    '20 instances of 145 bpm'
]

strip_zero = [x for x in result_list if not '0 instances' in x]

print(strip_zero)
```

Result:

```
['22 instances of 47 bpm', '354 instances of 65 bpm']
```

if I use this: `'\'0 instances'` 
instead of this: `'0 instances'`

none of the 0 instances are removed

Comment: You can use regular expressions with [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word)

Answer (score 6):

Use `startswith` instead.

```
result_list = [
    '0 instances of 44 bpm', 
    '0 instances of 45 bpm', 
    '10 instances of 46 bpm', 
    '22 instances of 47 bpm', 
    '354 instances of 65 bpm', 
    '20 instances of 145 bpm'
]

strip_zero = [x for x in result_list if not x.startswith('0 instances')]

print(strip_zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split the number (anything before first space) and check if it's zero:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result_list = [
        '0 instances of 44 bpm',
        '0 instances of 45 bpm',
        '10 instances of 46 bpm',
        '22 instances of 47 bpm',
        '354 instances of 65 bpm',
        '20 instances of 145 bpm'
    ]
    non_zeros = [r for r in result_list if r.split(' ', 1)[0] != '0']
    print(non_zeros)
```

output:

```
[
'10 instances of 46 bpm', 
'22 instances of 47 bpm', 
'354 instances of 65 bpm', 
'20 instances of 145 bpm'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just check if the first character is equal to '0', saves you from having to scan every string.

```py
strip_zero = [x for x in result_list if x[0] != '0']
```

Should be much quicker, and simpler to read really.