# Find specific words on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I look for a word in a data frame it shows me every entry containing those letters but I really want for it to show me that specific word. Can you help me out?

Here is and example:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['ROL', 'ROVER','ROL','ROLLER','ROL','TROLLER','rol','rolter','nan'] ,'col2': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```py
ROL = df[df['col1'].fillna(0).str.contains("ROL|rol",na=False)]
```

The output is something like this

[image: current output image]

but what I really wanted was something without those entries

[image: desired output image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: sorry. i believe it added value and helped explain my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your `str.contains("ROL|rol")` matches all values apart from `ROVER`. For example, `"ROLLER"` also contains `"ROL"`.

Try this use of `str.contains`:

```
import re
ids = df.col1.str.contains('rol$|rol-|rol ', flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex = True, na = False)
```

And then filter:

```
df[ids]
```

gives:

```
Out[115]: 
       col1  col2
0       ROL     1
2   ROL- 33     3
4    ROL -2     5
6  rol nº12     7
```

Comment: whats is the re. function ? because it shows : NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: Its a method you have to import. Run `import re` at the beginning of your code.