# Python regular expression to match string but not substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```py
s = 'ABC123ABC 23AB'
```

I need to replace the `23AB` with '', so the result is:

```py
s = 'ABC123ABC'
```

I have tried:

```py
s = re.sub('\d+AB', '', s)
```

but this also replaces it in `ABC123ABC`

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'\s*\d+AB\b', '', s)` or `re.sub(r'\s*\b\d+AB\b', '', s)` - see https://ideone.com/46W2jj

Comment: Duplicate of [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863066/python-regular-expression-match-whole-word)

Answer (score -1):

You could add `\b` which is word boundary to ensure there is no other stuff around what you look for, and `\s*` to remove the spaces too

```
import re
val = "ABC123ABC 23AB"
val = re.sub(r'\s*\b\d+AB\b', '', val)
print(val)
```